# Freetype with opengl shows no text

Tags: c, opengl, freetype

I’m trying to add freetype text to my running program. The code below was adapted from EdoardoLuciani. No text is shown, though.

I checked if the the tff file is loaded correctly and that valid textures ids are generated. They are o.k.

The remaining of the program is running without problem, but no text is drawn.

Could you help me to find what's wrong, please?

Environment:

DELL XPS

GPU 1050

OpenGL 4.6

Win32

Language C

```
// Main program

...
initText()
...

// Drawing loop

...
{
    drawText(10, 300, "Hello World!");
}

void initText()
{
    // Extract glyphs textures
    //
    glUseProgram(textShader);
    FT_Library ft;
    FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
    FT_Face face;
    FT_New_Face(ft, "arial.ttf", 0, &face);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    for(int c = 0; c < 128; c++)
    {
        FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER);
        //
        // Extract glyph
        //
        GLuint texture;
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1, &texture);
        glTextureStorage2D(texture, 1, GL_R8, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows);
        glTextureSubImage2D(texture, 0, 0, 0, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        //
        // Save glyph to lookup table
        //
        Character ch;
        ch.texture = texture;
        ch.bearing[0] = face->glyph->bitmap.width;
        ch.bearing[1] = face->glyph->bitmap.rows;
        ch.size[0] = face->glyph->bitmap_left;
        ch.size[1] = face->glyph->bitmap_top;
        ch.advance = face->glyph->advance.x;
        characters[c] = ch;
    }
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
    //
    // Create VAO
    //
    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &textVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(textVAO);
    //
    // Create the unique VBO
    //
    glCreateBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glNamedBufferStorage(VBO, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(textVAO, 0, VBO, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(textVAO, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(textVAO, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(textVAO, 0);
    //
    // Send color to fragment shader
    //
    glUniform3f(6, 0.88f, 0.59f, 0.07f);
}

void drawText(float x, float y, float scale, char *text)
{
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glUseProgram(textShader);
    glBindVertexArray(textVAO);
    //
    // Draw each character
    //
    char *c = text;
    while(*c != 0)
    {
        Character ch = characters[(int)*c];
        if(ch.bearing[0] != 0 && ch.bearing[1] != 0)
        {
            GLfloat xpos = x + ch.bearing[0] * scale;
            GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.size[1] - ch.bearing[1]) * scale;
            //
            GLfloat w = ch.size[0] * scale;
            GLfloat h = ch.size[1] * scale;
            //
            // Update VBO for each character
            //
            GLfloat vertices[6*4] =
            {
                xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0f, 0.0f ,
                xpos,     ypos,       0.0f, 1.0f ,
                xpos + w, ypos,       1.0f, 1.0f ,

                xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0f, 0.0f ,
                xpos + w, ypos,       1.0f, 1.0f ,
                xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0f, 0.0f
            };
            glNamedBufferSubData(VBO, 0, sizeof(GLfloat)*6*4, vertices);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.texture);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        }
        x += (ch.advance >> 6) * scale;
        c++;
    }
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 pos, vec2 tex>
layout (location = 1) uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 460 core

in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D text;
layout (location = 6) uniform vec3 textColor;

void main()
{    
    color = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * texture(text, TexCoords).r;
}
```

Comment: What is the projection matrix? Have you tried without face culling? (remove `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);`)

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your reply. 

The preojection matrix is

``` 
glmc_mat4_identity(projection); 
int loc = glGetUniformLocation(textShader, "projection"); 
glm_ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f, 0, 1000, projection); 
glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection[0]);
```


I removed the gl_enable(). The text appears now, but it is distorted, with variable width and spacing.